# Replacing string in sql query

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, replace

This is how I retrieve data

```
select myPlan from myTable
```

this is result ,

```
        myPlan
=====================
True  , False , True
False , True  , False
False , True  , True
```

In each row , I have three Boolean value separated by comma .
The first Boolean value represent Breakfast , the second is Lunch and the last is Dinner .

I just want to replace the result to

```
        myPlan
=====================
BreakFast , Dinner
Lunch
Lunch , Dinner
```

Can I make this replacement by using only `sql query` ?
I'm using `SQL server 2008 R2` !

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: It would be much simpler if you had a normalized database with 3 distinct boolean columns instead of one complex CHAR column ;)

Comment: @Frazz :) . I totally agree . I will obey that database normalization in next time . Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have just 3 booleans you could use a case statement for all 8 possibilities.

```
SELECT
    (CASE
    WHEN myPlan = 'True , True , True'
    THEN 'Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner'
    WHEN myPlan = 'True , True , False'
    THEN 'Breakfast, Lunch'
    WHEN myPlan = 'True , False , False'
    THEN 'Breakfast'
    WHEN myPlan = 'True , False , True'
    THEN 'Breakfast, Dinner'
    WHEN myPlan = 'False , False , True'
    THEN 'Dinner'
    WHEN myPlan = 'False , True , True'
    THEN 'Lunch, Dinner'
    WHEN myPlan = 'False , True , False'
    THEN 'Lunch'
    ELSE ''
    END) myPlan
FROM myTable
```

Comment: +1 because this seems to be quite reasonable given the table design!

Comment: +1 but you should probably add the 9th option of 3xFalse

Comment: @Szymon 3xFalse is covered by `ELSE ''`

Comment: Only problem with this is that space formatting is important, but then again - the design is not ..... "optimal" to begin with :)
So I'd propery do a replacement of spaces and comma with empty and then lower case it all so you get a 'truetruetrue' string for first case

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen , I've remove spaces using `Replace(myPlan, ' ', '')` . Whatever , FuzzyTree's answer work perfectly . :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use string functions as follows.

```
DECLARE @TEMP AS TABLE(MyPlan VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @TEMP(MyPlan) VALUES ('True  , False , True')
INSERT INTO @TEMP(MyPlan) VALUES ('False , True  , False')
INSERT INTO @TEMP(MyPlan) VALUES ('False , True  , True')

SELECT

     CASE 
        WHEN RTRIM(SUBSTRING(MyPlan,1,5)) = 'TRUE' THEN 'BREAKFAST'
        ELSE '' 
    END 
    +CASE 
        WHEN RTRIM(SUBSTRING(MyPlan,9,5)) = 'TRUE' THEN ',LUNCH'
        ELSE '' 
    END 
    +CASE 
        WHEN RTRIM(SUBSTRING(MyPlan,17,5)) = 'TRUE' THEN ',DINNER'
        ELSE '' 
    END 

FROM @TEMP
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter solution:

```
select 
decode(substr(myPlan,0,1),'T','Breakfast',null) ||  decode(substr(myPlan,0,1),'T',' , ',null) ||
decode(substr(myPlan,9,1),'T','Lunch',null) ||  decode(substr(myPlan,9,1),'T',' , ',null) ||
decode(substr(myPlan,17,1),'T','Dinner',null) 
from mytable;
```

Comment: The OP uses MS SQL2008.  decode is an Oracle function.  (substr would be SUBSTRING in MS SQL